# Keyframes not producing any animation effect

Tags: css

I am trying to do a quick animation in CSS an I am having difficulty doing it.  The objective is to slide the image to the left when I hover on it.  Where am I going wrong?  I get "Sorry, the at-rule @-webkit-keyframes is not implemented." on validator.org here is the CSS and HTML code.

**CSS:**

```
body {
     background-color:#d9d6cb;
}
#title {
     font-family:Agency FB;
     text-shadow:5px 0px 3px gray;
     text-align:center;
}
#mygallery{
     width:580px;
     padding:20px;
     margin-left: auto;
     margin-right: auto;
     background:black;
}
#fullimage 
{
     list-style:none;
     width:580px;
     height:400px;
     margin:0;
     padding:0;
     overflow:hidden;
}
#thumbimage
{
     list-style:none;
     overflow:auto;
     float:right;
     margin-left:5px;
     border-color:white;
     opacity:.5;
}
#thumbimage:hover{
     opacity:1; 
     -webkit-animation: slideImage 1s;
     animation: slideImage 1s;
}
@-webkit-keyframes slideImage{
     0%:{left:-700px;}
     100%{left:0px;}
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Index</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Gallery/CSS/style.css">
</head>

<body>
     <h1 id="title"> Image Gallery </h1>

    <div id="mygallery">
        <ul id="fullimage">
            <li>
                <img id="house" src="Gallery/Images/House.jpg" alt="House" width="580">
                <p><span> House </span>
                </p>
            </li>
            <li>
                <img id="tree" src="Gallery/Images/tree.jpg" alt="Tree" width="580">
                <p><span> Tree </span>
                </p>
            </li>
            <li>
                <img id="hobbithole" src="Gallery/Images/HobbitHole.jpg" alt="Hobbit Hole" width="580">
                <p><span> Hobbit Hole </span>
                </p>
            </li>
            <li>
                <img id="horses" src="Gallery/Images/horses.jpg" alt="Horses" width="580">
                <p><span> Horses </span>
                </p>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <ul id="thumbimage">
            <li><a href="Gallery/Images/House.jpg"><img src ="Gallery/Images/House.jpg" alt = "House" width = "50"></a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="Gallery/Images/tree.jpg"><img src ="Gallery/Images/tree.jpg" alt = "tree" width = "50"></a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="Gallery/Images/HobbitHole.jpg"><img src ="Gallery/Images/HobbitHole.jpg" alt = "Hobbit Hole" width = "50"></a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="Gallery/Images/horses.jpg"><img src ="Gallery/Images/horses.jpg" alt = "horses" width = "50"></a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Can you make a JSFiddle ? Your HTML structure is important too

Comment: add position on class `thumbimage` or change `left:-700px` to `margin-left`

Comment: There seems to be a typo in `0%:{left:-700px;}`. The `:` is not required there.

Answer (score 0):

Here i have made simple example please check out and make change as per your requirement:

[**Check JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/d0xoLnua/)

CSS:

```
@-webkit-keyframes slideImage{
0%:{left:-0px;}
100%{left:20px;}
}
body {
background-color:#d9d6cb;
}

#myimg{
    position:relative;
    left:200px;
    opacity:0.8;
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    padding:20px;
    background:black;
}

#myimg:hover{
     opacity:1; 
    -webkit-animation: slideImage 2s;
     animation: slideImage 1s;
}
```

Comment: I still can't figure it out.  Here is the accompanying HTML code.  I'm trying to make the thumbnail images slide.

Comment: Just Accept answer if it helpful to you